# Should the measurement uncertainty be included in the random uncertainty?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, titration

So, the other day I was carrying out a titration and got the titres $33.4cm^3$ and $33.3cm^3$. I calculated the random uncertainty to be $0.05cm^3$. Now, the burette itself had an uncertainty of and I'm wondering whether I should add these two uncertainties together to find the uncertainty for the titres. Also, if I have to use the average of the titres to calculate the percentage uncertainty or whether I need to calculate the percentage uncertainty individually for the titres.

Comment: Related: [Significant figures when standard deviation is 0](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/40213/7951)

Comment: Via interpolation you should be able to read a burette to 0.01 ml. It depends on the class of burette, but I'd think all would be better than 0.05 ml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - to calculate the total uncertainty when adding or subtracting measurements, it's the room-sum-squared of all the uncertainties.

$$
e_{tot} = \sqrt{(e_{meas})^2 + (e_{rand})^2}
$$
The more generalized form of this will be the root-sum-squared of all sources of error and uncertainty.
$$
e_{tot} = \sqrt{\sum{(e_n)^2}}  
$$

To get the quantity "$e_{meas}$" you apply the root-sum-squared formula of all the uncertainties of your measurement devices used to transfer liquids (transfer beaker, graduated cylinder, burette, etc...).

$$
e_{meas} = \sqrt{(e_{beaker})^2 + (e_{burette})^2+(e_{grad.cyl})^2+(e_{burette})^2...etc}
$$

=========

To answer whether you apply the burette uncertainty to your measurement, the answer is also yes. Assuming that the burette has an uncertainty of $±0.01 cm^3$, the actual reading of your measurements will be: $33.3cm^3 ± 0.01 mL$ and $33.4cm^3 ± 0.01 mL$. The two uncertainties in the measurement will be applied to the $e_{tot}$ equation above.

Comment: You can't end up with a measurement that has multiple kinds of units (i.e. statement *However, in the case that your measurement devices use different units*). If you're adding and subtracting then you use rms of error. If you're using multiplication and division then you use the rms of the % error.

Comment: Oh yikes, I've cleared that up to not cause confusion and specifying that these error calculations pertain only to addition and subtraction of measurements.