# Propagation of Uncertainties

Tags: titration

I have five values for the volume of sodium hydroxide needed to neutralise a fixed quantity of hydrochloric acid, each trial with an uncertainty of 0.05 mL. If I take the average of these five values, in what way would the uncertainty propagate? I can think of three of the following ways, but don't understand which would be correct:

1. Because we can see the calculation of an average as the sum of the values for the five trials (with their uncertainties), and then a division by 5, we sum up the uncertainty to get 0.25 mL and then divide it by 5 to get **the uncertainty of the average to be 0.05 mL.**
2. Because we can see the calculation of an average as the sum of the values for the five trials (with their uncertainties), and then a division by 5 ***(which has no uncertainty)***, we sum up the uncertainty to get 0.25 mL and then divide it by 5 to get **the uncertainty of the average to be 0.25 mL.**
3. Range divided by two is often another way to calculate the uncertainty of an average value, which for my case results in a value different to the above two for the uncertainty of the average.

Which one, and why, would be the correct one to state next to the average value (with a plus-minus sign), as an uncertainty of the average value?

Comment: Related: [Uncertainties after Averaging Trials](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/39583/7951)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of your methods are correct. If you have a small data set - in this case, 5 values from a titration - then the absolute uncertainty for each individual value is half the range of data. For example, say you get the following results (in ml, from a burette with a precision of 0.05ml): $4.70$, $5.35$, $4.85$, $4.60$ and $5.20$. The range of these results is $5.35-4.60=0.75$. This gives an absolute uncertainty of $\frac{0.75}{2}=0.375$ for each individual piece of data e.g. $4.85\pm0.38$ml.

However, if the absolute uncertainty calculated from half the range is less than the precision of the instrument (in this case $<0.05$ ), then the precision of the instrument should be given as the uncertainty e.g. $5.00\pm0.05$. I think you may have incorrectly calculated the absolute uncertainties.

For small data sets ($<10$ pieces of data), the uncertainty in the mean is then given by $$\Delta {x}_{avg}=\frac{\Delta x}{\sqrt{N}}=\frac{R}{2\sqrt{N}}$$ where $\Delta {x}_{avg}$ is the uncertainty in the mean, ${N}$ is the number of times the measurement was repeated, $R$ is the range and $\Delta{x}$ is the uncertainty in one measurement.

For example, using the example data above, $\Delta {x}_{avg}=\frac{0.375}{\sqrt{5}}=0.168$. The average can then be stated as $4.94\pm0.17$ml

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you understand what you're asking. Ambler's answer gives you the correct procedure to handle your experimental measurement error.

But there is also an inherent error against which you could do an F-Test to see if your experimental variation was within the limits of the error of the burette.

When you say that "each trial with an uncertainty of 0.05 mL" what you're really saying is that the error is +/- 0.05 for each trial which means that the error could be -0.05, -0.04, -0.03, ..., +0.03. +0.04, +0.05 with equal probability. so over 5 reading the expected error could be as low as -0.25 and as high as +0.25.

So the expected variance over the samples combined is:

$V(n) = \dfrac{0.1*n}{12}$

the variance of the mean is $1/\sqrt{n}$ smaller so:

$\sigma_{mean} = \dfrac{0.1*\sqrt{n}}{12}$

where $n$ is the number of repetitions of the measurement.